# Can't get @Resource annotation to work in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, resources

I've been working on a project with Websockets and I needed the same HashMap in multiple classes and threads. After reading for a bit I figured out that using @Resource annotation would be the best. But I can't get it to work, and I am getting only null when printing String and getting  NullPointerException when doing anything with ConcurrentHashMap. Here is part of the code.

**SocketHandler.java**

```
@Component
public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Resource(name = "teststring")
    private String testString;

    private ConcurrentHashMap<WebSocketSession, UserPlayer> sessions;

    @Resource(name="sessions")
    public void setSessions(ConcurrentHashMap<WebSocketSession, UserPlayer> sessions){
        System.out.println("Im in @resource");
        this.sessions=sessions;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(final WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(testString);
        sessions.put(session, new UserPlayer());
        System.out.println("Got connection " + session);
    }
}
```

**AplicationContextResource.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextResource{

    @Bean(name="sessions")
    public ConcurrentHashMap<WebSocketSession, UserPlayer> sessions(){
        ConcurrentHashMap<WebSocketSession, UserPlayer> sessions = new  ConcurrentHashMap<WebSocketSession, UserPlayer>();
        System.out.println("bean sessions!!");
        return sessions;
    }

    @Bean(name="teststring")
    public String testString(){
        String str = new String("12345");
        return str;
    }
}
```

**BeanPostProc.java**

```
@Configuration
public class BeanPostProc {

    @Bean
    public CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor commonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(){
        CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor cBeanPostProcessor = new CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
        cBeanPostProcessor.setAlwaysUseJndiLookup(true);
        return cBeanPostProcessor;
    }
}
```

And this is the console output after server starts and client connects.

```
020-05-07 22:03:28.417  INFO 3132 --- [           main] com.soluna.slith.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on Racunalo with PID 3132 (D:\Git\slytherin\server\slith\target\classes started by Sebastijan in d:\Git\slytherin\server\slith)
2020-05-07 22:03:28.421  INFO 3132 --- [           main] com.soluna.slith.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-07 22:03:29.395  INFO 3132 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'beanPostProc' of type [com.soluna.slith.config.BeanPostProc$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$524027f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-07 22:03:29.758  INFO 3132 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-07 22:03:29.771  INFO 3132 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-07 22:03:29.772  INFO 3132 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-05-07 22:03:29.874  INFO 3132 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-07 22:03:29.875  INFO 3132 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1365 ms
bean sessions!!
Im in @resource
2020-05-07 22:03:30.193  INFO 3132 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-07 22:03:30.458  INFO 3132 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-07 22:03:30.461  INFO 3132 --- [           main] com.soluna.slith.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.511 seconds (JVM running for 3.154)
2020-05-07 22:04:31.705  INFO 3132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-07 22:04:31.705  INFO 3132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-07 22:04:31.722  INFO 3132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 17 ms
null
2020-05-07 22:04:31.808 ERROR 3132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.s.h.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator : Closing session due to exception for StandardWebSocketSession[id=6aedf417-075a-851d-bb92-16e32ef76915, uri=ws://localhost:8080/game]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.soluna.slith.controller.SocketHandler.afterConnectionEstablished(SocketHandler.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
```

My project has no XML, all examples showed XML-based bean configuration. Tried with and without .setAlwaysUseJndiLookup(true). Did I mess up somehow with CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading and trying a lot of things I've finally found the error.
The error wasn't in any of above classes, but in WebSocket configuration.
BeanPostProc.java with CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor isn't even needed.

WebSocket configuration **before**:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSocket 
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override 
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketHandler(), "/game").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
  }
```

WebSocket configuration **now**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private SocketHandler socketHandler;

    @Override 
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(socketHandler, "/game").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

The error was that I was making a new instance of SocketHandler that wasn't managed by Spring and wasn't autowired properly.
Bean injections are working with @Resource and @Autowired annotations after fixing the error.